# graph logistic regression spline, with fixed knots at quartiles in SPSS

Tags: spss, spline, logistic-regression

So I have done my analyses and now I'd like to construct a spline of my logistic regression with 3 knots (at quartile values). On the Y-axis I want odds and on the X-axis I want my linear variable V (between 0 and 500) which I have binned in quartiles in my analysis.
The outcome table is something like this:

```
                 B       SE     exp(B)   lowerbound upperbound
 quartiles(1)   0.15    0.329    1.16     0.60       2.18
 quartiles(2)   0.2     0.33     1.22     0.68       2.39
 quartiles(3)   1.2     0.299    3.32     1.70       6.2
```

however I'm not very familiar with SPSS and cannot quite figure it out, do i need to do this manually, and if so would it suffice to use something like:

```
     intercept+B1*dummy1*(V-Vquartile1max)+B2*dummy2*(V-Vquartile2max)+b3*dummy3*(V-Vquartile3max)? 

     #Not code but expanation: 
     dummy1= (quartile2=1, other quartiles=0)
     dummy2= (quartile3=1, other quartiles=0)
     dummy3= (quartile4=1, other quartiles=0)
```

Does anyone have any suggestions how to do it correctly because the formula I just wrote is way more suitable for linear than logistic regression, and I don't quite know how to fix it.

Kind regards

Comment: For splines in any regression equation you can simply calculate the variables yourself and include them on the right hand side (whether linear or logit or generalized linear it does not matter). I have a macro that calculates restricted cubic splines, see [this blog post](https://andrewpwheeler.wordpress.com/2013/06/06/restricted-cubic-splines-in-spss/) for an example.

Comment: Oke this is very helpful, to summarize: You have x and y values and fit a logistic regression model over it and save the predictive values, however i'm not quite clear as to how you obtain: splinex1 splinex2 which are used in the logistic regression, I don't know the command ICI (after PRED) but is that a command for 95% confidence interval (lower and upper bound)? In any case it's helpful, Thank you

Comment: `ICIN` is for *prediction* intervals after linear regression (with the default 95%). The different regression procedures vary slightly, but all of them have a `/SAVE` subcommand in which you can save the confidence intervals. You just calculate splinex1 and splinex2 *before* the regression procedure using `COMPUTE` commands. You've already shown the logic for linear splines in your question.